# How to read a text file into a list or an array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, text

I am trying to read the lines of a text file into a list or array in python.  I just need to be able to individually access any item in the list or array after it is created.

The text file is formatted as follows:

```
0,0,200,0,53,1,0,255,...,0.
```

Where the `...` is above, there actual text file has hundreds or thousands more items.

I'm using the following code to try to read the file into a list:

```
text_file = open("filename.dat", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
print lines
print len(lines)
text_file.close()
```

The output I get is:

```
['0,0,200,0,53,1,0,255,...,0.']
1
```

Apparently it is reading the entire file into a list of just one item, rather than a list of individual items.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as a note.  It looks like this question should be rephrased as how to read a csv file into a list in Python.  But I defer to the OP's original intentions over 4 years ago which I don't know.

Comment: Related, likely duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: **As asked** this is definitely a duplicate of the question @AMC found. **As titled**, this is clickbait for [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503). This should be deleted as it was poorly asked (did not correctly identify the issue, which is **not related to** the file reading), is a bad signpost (because of the titling and overall framing of the question), and the answers do not provide any unique insights (this material is so basic that there is nothing unique to offer).

Answer (score 191):

You will have to split your string into a list of values using `split()`

So,

```
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
```

EDIT:
I didn't realise there would be so much traction to this. Here's a more idiomatic approach.

```py
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as fd:
    reader = csv.reader(fd)
    for row in reader:
        # do something
```

Comment: I think that this answer could be bettered... If you consider a
multiline `.csv` file (as mentioned by the OP), e.g., a file
containing the alphabetic characters 3 by row (`a,b,c`, `d,e,f`, etc)
and apply the procedure described above what you get is a list like
this: `['a', 'b', 'c\nd', 'e', ... ]` (note the item `'c\nd'`).

I'd like to add that, the above problem notwistanding, this procedure
collapses data from individual rows in a single mega-list, usually not
what I want when processing a record-oriented data file.

Comment: split is going to leave the newlines. Don't do this, use `csv` module or some other existing parser

Answer (score 68):

You can also use numpy loadtxt like

```
from numpy import loadtxt
lines = loadtxt("filename.dat", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False)
```

Comment: I need this too. I noticed on a Raspberry Pi that numpy works really slow. For this application I reverted to open a file and read it line by line.

Comment: This is useful for specifying format too, via `dtype : data-type` parameter. 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html 
Pandas read_csv is very easy to use. But I did not see a way to specify format for it. It was reading floats from my file, whereas I needed string. Thanks @Thiru for showing loadtxt.

Comment: if txt files contains strings, then dtype should be specified, so it should be like lines = loadtxt("filename.dat", dtype=str, comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=False)

Answer (score 28):

So you want to create a list of lists... We need to start with an empty list

```
list_of_lists = []
```

next, we read the file content, line by line

```
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split(',')]
        # in alternative, if you need to use the file content as numbers
        # inner_list = [int(elt.strip()) for elt in line.split(',')]
        list_of_lists.append(inner_list)
```

A common use case is that of columnar data, but our units of storage are the
rows of the file, that we have read one by one, so you may want to *transpose*
your list of lists.  This can be done with the following idiom

```
by_cols = zip(*list_of_lists)
```

Another common use is to give a name to each column

```
col_names = ('apples sold', 'pears sold', 'apples revenue', 'pears revenue')
by_names = {}
for i, col_name in enumerate(col_names):
    by_names[col_name] = by_cols[i]
```

so that you can operate on homogeneous data items

```
 mean_apple_prices = [money/fruits for money, fruits in
                     zip(by_names['apples revenue'], by_names['apples_sold'])]
```

Most of what I've written can be speeded up using the `csv` module, from the standard library.  Another third party module is `pandas`, that lets you automate most aspects of a typical data analysis (but has a number of dependencies).

---

*Update* While in Python 2 `zip(*list_of_lists)` returns a different (transposed) list of lists, in Python 3 the situation has changed and `zip(*list_of_lists)` returns *a zip object* that is not subscriptable.

If you *need* indexed access you can use

```
by_cols = list(zip(*list_of_lists))
```

that gives you a list of lists in both versions of Python.

On the other hand, if you *don't need* indexed access and what you want is just to build a dictionary indexed by column names, a zip object is just fine...

```
file = open('some_data.csv')
names = get_names(next(file))
columns = zip(*((x.strip() for x in line.split(',')) for line in file)))
d = {}
for name, column in zip(names, columns): d[name] = column
```

Comment: The OP said they wanted a list of data from a CSV, not a "list of lists". Just use the `csv` module...

Answer (score 8):

**This question is asking how to read the comma-separated value contents from a file into an iterable list:**

`0,0,200,0,53,1,0,255,...,0.`

**The easiest way to do this is with the `csv` module as follows:**

```
import csv
with open('filename.dat', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

**Now, you can easily iterate over `spamreader` like this:**

```
for row in spamreader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

**See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) for more examples.**

Answer (score 3):

Im a bit late but you can also read the text file into a dataframe and then convert corresponding column to a list.

```
lista=pd.read_csv('path_to_textfile.txt', sep=",", header=None)[0].tolist()
```

example.

```
lista=pd.read_csv('data/holdout.txt',sep=',',header=None)[0].tolist()
```

Note: the column name of the corresponding dataframe will be in the form of integers and i choose 0 because i was extracting only the first column

Comment: I suppose "pd" here stands for "pandas", so you'd need to import pandas for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Better this way,

```
 def txt_to_lst(file_path):

    try:
        stopword=open(file_path,"r")
        lines = stopword.read().split('\n')
        print(lines)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *Why* is this better?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build in Python function `.eval()`

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text_list = eval(text)
```

The output is:

```
text:     '[0,0,200,0,53,1,0,255]'
text_list: [0, 0, 200, 0, 53, 1, 0, 255]
```

> Python's eval() allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input. This function can be handy when you're trying to dynamically evaluate Python expressions from any input that comes as a string or a compiled code object. [source](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/), [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)