# For loop iterating through values in file

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and want to extract integers from an csv file and if they meet certain parameters I want my program to execute an update 'H' or 'T'. My question is how do I import the values from my csv file into this for loop?

```
def main():
    suite = Euro(range(0, 101))
    for i in range(0, 32):
        suite.Update('H')
    for i in range(0, 9):
        suite.Update('T')
```

Edit: The input csv file looks like below.

```
Cheq1, Cheq2      
113, 130
105, 138
0, 128
142, 142
96, 137
```

Comment: Use the csv library https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html, adding what your input looks like and your expected output  would help

Comment: Have you looked at the `csv` package? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Comment: Thank you, I made it work correctly after reading the document in the python library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
print your_list
# [['Cheq1', 'Cheq2'],
#  ['113', '130'],
#  ['0', '128']]
# ...
```

You should be able to handle it from there.