# How to upload a worksheet using pygsheets

Tags: python, json, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I'm working with http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html a wrapper around the google sheets api v4.

I have a small script where I am trying to select a json sheet to upload to a google sheets worksheet. The file name is made up of the:

```
spreadsheetname_year_month_xxx.json
```

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import pygsheets


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
print file_path
file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
print file_name
file_name_segments = file_name.split('_')
spreadsheet = file_name_segments[0]
worksheet = file_name_segments[1]+'_'+file_name_segments[2]

gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file='client_secret_xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json')

ssheet = gc.open(spreadsheet)
ws = ssheet.add_worksheet(worksheet(ssheet,str(raw_input(file_path))))
```

The file path leads to a generated json file that looks like:

```
{
  "count": 12, 
  "results": [
    {
      "case": "abc1", 
      "case_name": "invalid", 
      "case_type": "invalid", 

    }, 
    {
      "case": "abc2", 
      "case_name": "invalid", 
      "case_type": "invalid", 
      },
............
```

I am getting :

```
File "upload_to_google_sheets.py", line 27, in <module>
ws = ssheet.add_worksheet(worksheet(ssheet,str(raw_input(file_path))))
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

As you can see I'm trying to instantiate a worksheet with the json data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you are doing it right? because the jsonSheet param contains the properties of the worksheet sheet, hence should be of this format https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet . Are you trying to update the sheet with the values in the json document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JsonSheet`  param is not for values of the worksheet, it is for specifying the properties of the worksheet, hence should be of [this](http://The%20%60JsonSheet%60%20%20param%20is%20not%20for%20values%20of%20the%20worksheet,%20it%20is%20for%20specifying%20the%20properties%20of%20the%20worksheet%20sheet%20,%20hence%20should%20be%20of%20[this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Sheet)%20format.) format.

As directly converting a json to spreadsheet is rather ambiguous, you will need to first convert it to a numpy array (matrix) or an pandas DataFrame. Then you can use `set_as_df` of just `update_values` for updating the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I have created the pygsheets tag as you requested. I really appreciate your work here. I will investigate numpy arrays and pandas dfs. If I can ask a follow up: I have a lot of CSVs which I would like to upload, what would be your recommended approach using your library?

Comment: by numpy array i meant just a list of lists. About csv you could just use the csv module and read the csv's as matrix(list of lists), and use the update_cells. Or you can use the pandas  read_csv for reading csv and set_as_df. I would recommend using csv module as it might be a bit faster and pandas support might be removed as it's adding heavily to import time.

Comment: Thank you. I must have missed it, but where is the csv module in pygsheets?

Comment: pygsheets just take an generic matrix, you can use the csv module to read a csv into that format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Comment: I have a follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381184/conditional-formatting-with-pygsheets-for-google-sheets-api , if you have time.