# Conditional formatting with pygsheets for google sheets api

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

[image]

I'm working with http://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html a wrapper around the google sheets api v4. I am interested in setting conditional formatting using the google-sheets-api v4. I'm trying to use a custom formula to highlight a row based on the value of the "Q" column in the row. if the q column contains 'TRASH',  I want to colour the row red.

As I look through the pygheets library in https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/master/pygsheets/client.py I came across, which I believe is the way to send this request:

```
 # @TODO use batch update more efficiently
def sh_batch_update(self, spreadsheet_id, request, fields=None, batch=False):
    if type(request) == list:
        body = {'requests': request}
    else:
        body = {'requests': [request]}
    final_request = self.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body,
                                                            fields=fields)
return self._execute_request(spreadsheet_id, final_request, batch)
```

Further, in https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting#add_a_custom_formula_rule_to_a_range, an example is given on how to send a custom request. Based on this I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import pygsheets

def cfr1(sheetId):

    # Apply to range: A1:R
    # Format cells if...: Custom formula is
    # (formula:) =$Q1="TRASH"

    return {"requests": [
        {
          "addConditionalFormatRule": {
            "rule": {
              "ranges": [
                {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "startColumnIndex": 'A',
                  "endColumnIndex": 'R',
                  "startRowIndex": 1,
                  "endRowIndex": 8
                }
              ],
              "booleanRule": {
                "condition": {
                  "type": "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "userEnteredValue": '=$Q1="TRASH"'
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "format": {
                    "backgroundColor": {
                          "red": 1.0
                          # "green": 0.0,
                          # "blue": 0.0
                        }


                }
              }
            },
            "index": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
print file_path
file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
print file_name
file_name_segments = file_name.split('_')
spreadsheet = file_name_segments[0]
worksheet = file_name_segments[1]+'_'+file_name_segments[2]
print worksheet
print spreadsheet

gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file='client_secret_xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json')
a =gc.list_ssheets()
wb_list = [d['name'] for d in a]
print wb_list
if spreadsheet not in wb_list:
    print "Doesn't exist .."
else:
    ssheet = gc.open(spreadsheet)
    print ssheet.title
    print 'ws '+worksheet
    ws = ssheet.worksheet('title',worksheet)

    gc.sh_batch_update(ssheet.id,cfr1(ws.id),'A1:R8')
```

but I'm getting:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting htps://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Ypb_P**********pFt_SE:batchUpdate?fields=A1%3AR
8&alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Json payload  `return {"requests": [` you dont need the key `requests` as inside the `sh_batch_update` , its already wrapping it in requests. Take a look at the implimentation of `delete_cols` in `worksheet.py` to see an example usage.

So effectively you can just do,

```
return {
          "addConditionalFormatRule": {
            "rule": {
```

also you dont need to pass the range here `gc.sh_batch_update(ssheet.id,cfr1(ws.id),'A1:R8')` the fields param decides the response fields to return

Comment: Thank you, After making the changes you recommended, I'm getting  "Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_conditional_format_rule.rule.ranges[0].end_column_index.value' (TYPE_INT32), "R"
Invalid value at 'requests[0].add_conditional_format_rule.rule.ranges[0].start_column_index.value' (TYPE_INT32), "A""> . What I'm really trying to do in this case is apply the formatting to every row in the sheet, but couldn't find how to do that in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I realized you have to use column numbers, not letters,

Comment: If I could ask a quick follow up. How do you apply changes to entire sheet?

Comment: That would be great to know as well, but I meant all rows in a worksheet

Comment: just the change the range param in the format request to include all cells. hence put the start indexes as 1 and end index as the number of row/col (you can get number of colums from wks.cols and wks.rows)

Comment: Thank you. One last question If I may, I can see that the formatting is working, but I notice that if I enter the word "TRASH" in the appropriate column it colours that row and also the next row. I just want the same row coloured, not the next. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Sorry, The problem was when I was testing I had accidently created a series of overlapping conditional format rules. When I removed them in the worksheet manually things started working correctly.