# How can I transform csv data in python

Tags: python, csv, transform

I have a csv file that I want to transform. Currently the data looks like this in the csv file

```
115776 1142 1523 20197 20394 3421 1284 9572 19682
```

but I want it to look like this

```
115776 1142
115776 1523
115776 20197
115776 20394
115776 3421
```

.....

any idea on how to achieve this?

I currently wrote a function to get it and it gets it like this

```
for row in read_csv(testfile, "Recipes_RecipeId Recipes_Ingredients_0_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_1_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_2_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_3_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_4_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_5_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_6_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_7_IngredientID Recipes_Ingredients_8_IngredientID".split()):
    with open('recipeIngredientID.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

is there any better way to do it where it prints it out I want it?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Besides, what have you tried, whats the delimiting, is that all in one row in separate columns or in one cell? If you want help, help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the csv into a python list: [Python import csv to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list)

And then simply loop over the list with repeating the first index:

```
test = [115776, 1142, 1523, 20197, 20394, 3421, 1284, 9572, 19682]

for i in test[1:]:
     print test[0], i
```

Comment: The very first output of this is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller csv you can load csv to array of arrays, make empty rotated array and copy data. Like this...

```
head -n 10 vf.txt | python -c "
import sys
import csv
reader=csv.reader(sys.stdin)
mx = []
for row in reader:
    mx.append(row)

cols = len(mx[0])
rows = len(mx)
outp = [[None for e in range(0,rows) ] for i in range(0,cols)]
for r in range(0, rows):
    for c in range(0,cols):
        outp[c][r] = mx [r][c]

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
for r in outp:
    writer.writerow(r)
"""
```