# Read csv data by numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

For example, I have `csv` file contains ten columns. Is it possible to read it into two variables -- first one will contain 1-2..9 columns and second will contain last column by means of `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`?

Comment: You could read it into one big array `a` (very easy with `loadtxt`) and then look at two different slices, `a1 = a[:, :-1]` and `a2 = a[:, [-1]]`

Comment: Have you looked into the import csv module?
 This answer should get the job done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Comment: @Z.Bagley yes, but this is a `numpy` question, which already has functions to load csvs directly into `numpy` data structures. Using `csv` in this case is an unnecessary middleman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = numpy.loadtxt('blah.csv', delimiter=',')    # loads it all into one big array
a1 = a[:, :-1]    # a view of all but the last column
a2 = a[:, [-1]]   # a copy of just the last column
```

(Or, if you want your last-column variable to be one-dimensional, you can get a view of it using `a[:,-1]` instead of saying `a[:, [-1]]`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe `a[:, [-1]]` will be a view, but rather, a copy.

Comment: Yeah, likely you don't want a view anyways.

Comment: I'm wondering what would `a[:, -1][:, np.newaxis]` be? a view or copy?

Comment: @kmario23 a view, I think

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.loadtext('filename.csv', usecols(0,1,2,...,n-2))
numpy.loadtext('filename.csv', usecols = n-1)
```

Note: The index of your columns should be decremented by 1, as numpy would start at 0 when loading.

From the Documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html:

> usecols : int or sequence, optional
>   Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example, usecols = (1,4,5) will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns. The default, None, >results in all columns being read."

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't really need numpy. You could use pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/), or csv (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) libraries.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I can second the recommendation that the OP look into pandas—it sounds like they're about to do something for which pandas is very well-suited.