# Twitter - Getting account creation dates of multiple users from a csv file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get creation date of Twitter accounts from a csv file. I am not sure how would I go about it. I am still learning how to code so if someone can help me with this, it'll be a great help. Thank you in advance.

```
from twython import Twython
import pandas as pd
import requests

t = Twython(app_key='', 
            app_secret='',
            oauth_token='',
            oauth_token_secret='')

data = "file.xlsx"
handles = pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=None)

comma_separated_string = ",".join(data)

output = t.lookup_user(screen_name=comma_separated_string)
username_list=[]

for user in output:
username_list.append(user['created_at'])
print username_list
```

Comment: You'll need to give it a try first.  I'd suggest you do a little searching (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list) post) and then when you get stuck, you'll have at least a starting point for a question.

Comment: What have you actually done?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I posted an answer, which requires your valuable suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

, 
As a start, You should search about how to extract data from twitter  using python or extractting data from Twitter Api and you will learn how to build ur code and what you need to build it such as using Twitter access keys and tweepy library.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code at the moment:

```
    from twython import Twython
    import pandas as pd
    import requests

    t = Twython(app_key='', 
                app_secret='',
                oauth_token='',
                oauth_token_secret='')

    data = "file.xlsx"
    handles = pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=None)

    comma_separated_string = ",".join(data)

    output = t.lookup_user(screen_name=comma_separated_string)
    username_list=[]

    for user in output:
    username_list.append(user['created_at'])
    print username_list
```