# CSV to Pythonic List

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a CSV file into Python list I have strings organize in columns. I need an Automation to turn them into a list.
my code works with Pandas, but I only see them again as simple text.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("Random.csv", low_memory=False)
dicts = data.to_dict().values()
print(data)
```

so the final results should be something like that : ('Dan', 'Zac', 'David')

Comment: Your expected result is a tuple not a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by using csv module in python

```
import csv
with open('random.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = map(list, reader)

print your_list
```

You can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662707/8677188)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a list, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Random.csv', low_memory=False, header=None).iloc[:,0].tolist()
```

This produces

```
['Dan', 'Zac', 'David']
```

If you want a tuple instead, just cast the list:

```
data = tuple(pd.read_csv('Random.csv', low_memory=False, header=None).iloc[:,0].tolist())
```

And this produces

```
('Dan', 'Zac', 'David')
```

I assumed that you use commas as separators in your csv and your file has no header. If this is not the case, just change the params of `read_csv` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! you just didn't mention ''import pandas'' first! im all new to programming. anyway that solved my issues

Comment: @TaboliD: My bad, I will edit this immediately. I thought this was clear, as you have already imported it.