# How to move values from one to another row/ column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, data-manipulation

I am trying to write a python script that writes data from one csv file into another csv file that is structured differently

I am currently only able to just duplicate the data in in the structure of the source file.

```
!/usr/bin/env python3
#imports csv module

import csv

#opens file and reads
out=open("forecast_test.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)

with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as new_data:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_data)

        for line in data:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
            print (line)
```

The structure of the source file is below

```
 id,
123,
435,
765,
```

I want my script to write it to a csv file that is structured like below

```
 id, id2, id3
123, 435, 765
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's okay that the first column is `id0` not just `id`, but doing so saved the need of an if statement in a loop.

```py
import csv

datafile=open('forecast_test.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(datafile)

ls=[]
for r in reader:
    ls.append(r[0])

coltit=ls[0]

ls.pop(0)

lout=[]
lout1=[]
for x in ls:
    lout.append(str(coltit)+str(ls.index(x)))
    lout1.append(x)

with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as new_data:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_data)
    csv_writer.writerows([lout])
    csv_writer.writerows([lout1])
```

new_data.csv

```
id0,id1,id2
123,435,765
```

Comment: Hi Quick question though is there a way to keep the format below even if there isn't 5 indexes in the array?

So if the source csv has 2 rows of id's but the target csv should keep the 3 other id columns, but the values would be blank.

Comment: @2tone_tony I want to answer your question, I just need some clarification. I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "format below even"? I think you want to edit an existing CSV with row[0] and [1] both having variables in them and now you want to tack on more rows to their side? I'd say take a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list#answer-48106713>, but do `list(map(list,reader))`, so that way you are just working with a 2D list.

Comment: @2tone_tony Also, if I understand your question right, for example if you start with `csv=[[id0,id1],[123,312],[435,543],[765,576]]` You should then be able to `csv[0] = csv[0] + [id2,id3,id4]` and `csv[1] = csv[1] + [454,554,654]`, and then just use write the CSV normally. Also take a look at <https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer>, it might just be what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry I forgot to show an example after "format below"

`source csv file
id
--
123
234
564`

expected result in target

`id0  id1   id2   id3  id4  id5


 --     --     --     --     --     --


123  234  564`

Imagine the ID's are headers and that the numbers are below them.

Comment: @2tone_tony `csv_writer.writerows([lout1])` to `csv_writer.writerows([['','','','','','']+lout1])`. If you want more help send me your code; email on profile.