# Python: How to find max value in list of preceding 10 values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, max

I have a [csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PDOrrFB0WR99Da0kcG6_VotMnKxStJ0R/view?usp=sharing) containing wave data (time, tidal elevation, wave period, wave height and wave direction)
I want to know, at a given time, when the previous high tide was and the corresponding wave period, height and direction.

[image]

I have this code now which selects the line of the time that I'm looking for:

```
import csv

with open ('Waves_2019.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader (f)
    for line_num, content in enumerate(reader):
        if content [0] == '01/03/2019T08:00':
            a = line_num
            print (a)
```

The next step would then take the previous 12 hours of data to select the highest tidal elevation (0.77 at 01/03/2019T01:00 in example) and then return the other data (period, height, direction).

How could I amend the code that it looks for the max tidal elevation in column 2 based on the previous 12 data points of the selected time? And then return the other data during that high tide?

Comment: Please make your data available in CSV to play with.

Comment: Were you able to use the read line to make a list so if you want to read the contents of time='01/03/2019T08:00', you could simply do if csv_list[9][0]='01/03/2019T08:00': print(csv_list[9]). Let's say you want to get 12 previous values before this then simply index it to get all previous values, make a list, then find maximum of the list

Comment: You can use this to read the csv into a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we select the index of the date we require to examine

```
selected_index = df.loc[df["time"].eq("01/03/2019T08:00")].index[0]
```

Then obtain the id value having the maximum `tidal_elevation` from the previous 12 hours (since there are no missing rows in the dataset, we can safely assume that the previous 12 indices would indicate the 12 hours)

```
filt = df.loc[selected_index-12: selected_index, "tidal_elevation"].idxmax()
```

Now, we select other parameters for the index having maximum `tidal_elevation`

```
res = df.loc[filt, ["time", "tidal_elevation", "wave_period", "wave_height", "wave_direction"]]
print(res)
```

P.S. `res = df.loc[filt, "time":"wave_direction"]`
 would also work if the chronology of the columns is the same i.e. it is in the same order `["time", "tidal_elevation", "wave_period", "wave_height", "wave_direction"]`

Edit:
Taking average of values one hour before and after the maximum `tidal_elevation`

```
res_avg = df.loc[filt-1:filt+1, "time":"wave_direction"].mean()
print(res_avg)
```

Comment: does the answer help your use-case?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks @JohnDoe.
Would it be possible to amend this and take the average of the different columns after selecting high tide (1 hour before high tide + high tide + 1 hour after high tide)?

Comment: I wanted to build on your code that you helped me with by exporting all the necessary data to a csv file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484795/python-select-different-row-values-from-csv-and-combine-them-in-new-csv
@JohnDoe