# Import two columns from csv into python under one header numpy list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set that consists of two columns as coordinates. I would like to import them to python under one header list called "coordinates". Does anyone have any solution?. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list

Comment: This query is about how to import csv as a list. I would like to combine two columns under one header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `df.values.tolist()`.

First select the columns from the name of your dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(name_of_dataframe, columns= ['col1', 'col2'])`

Next change it to a list: `list = df.values.tolist()`.

Then flatten the list with a loop appending each smaller list into one bigger list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with csv module.

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv') as file:
    coordinates = [(float(x), float(y)) for x, y in csv.reader(file, delimiter= ',')]
```