# Python import csv to dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Excuse me. I am a noob
I saw
[Python import csv to list Pandas #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list/40788179#40788179)

if I have this csv

```
country    population      population_time    EUR
Germany    82521653.0      2016-12-01         True
France     66991000.0      2017-01-01         True
Indonesia  255461700.0     2017-01-01         False
Ireland    4761865.0       NaT                True
Spain      46549045.0      2017-06-01         True
Vatican    NaN             NaT                True
```

How to change like this

```
[{'country': 'Germany', 'population': 82521653.0, 'population_time': Timestamp('2016-12-0100:00:00'), 'EUR': True},
{'country': 'France', 'population': 66991000.0, 'population_time': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'EUR': True},
{'country': 'Indonesia', 'population': 255461700.0, 'population_time': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'EUR': False},
{'country': 'Ireland', 'population': 4761865.0, 'population_time': NaT, 'EUR': True},
{'country': 'Spain', 'population': 46549045.0, 'population_time': Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:00:00'), 'EUR': True},
{'country': 'Vatican', 'population': nan, 'population_time': NaT, 'EUR': True}]
```

I just can do like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(df.to_dict())
```

result:

```
{'country':{0:'Germany', 1:'France', 2:'Indonesia', 3:'Ireland', 4:'Spain', 5:'Vatican'},
 'population ':{0:'82521653.0', 1:'66991000.0', 2:'255461700.0', 3:'4761865.0', 4:'46549045.0', 5:'NaN'},
 'population_time':{0:'2016-12-01', 1:'2017-01-01', 2:'2017-01-01', 3:'NaT', 4:'2017-06-01', 5:'NaT'},
 'EUR':{0:'True', 1:'True', 2:'False', 3:'True', 4:'True', 5:'True'},
```

Comment: `with open('path/to/csv') as infile: answer = list(csv.DictReader(infile))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. Little change to your code. Notice the keyword argument 'orient'.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

It gives the following output

```py
[{'country': 'Germany', 'population': 82521653.0, 'opulation_time': '2016-12-01', 'EUR': True}, {'country': 'France', 'population': 66991000.0, 'opulation_time': '2017-01-01', 'EUR': True}, {'country': 'Indonesia', 'population': 255461700.0, 'opulation_time': ' 2017-01-01', 'EUR': False}, {'country': 'Ireland', 'population': 4761865.0, 'opulation_time': 'NaT', 'EUR': True}, {'country': 'Spain', 'population': 46549045.0, 'opulation_time': '2017-06-01', 'EUR': True}, {'country': 'Vatican', 'population': nan, 'opulation_time': 'NaT', 'EUR': True}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`df.to_dict(orient='records')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.DictReader` for that:

```py
import csv

with open('t.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    data = [d for d in reader]
```