# Split CSV file using python

Tags: python

I'm looking for some advice on how to split CSV file using Python. I'm new to Python and strugling with finding the easiest way to achieve it.

Here is the simple example that data I'm trying to split:

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | tag1;tag2;tag3; |

and here is what I would like data to be presented after:

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | tag1 |
| 01 | tag2 |
| 01 | tag3 |

Remark here is that column "tags" can hold the unlimited number of values.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Here is what worked for me. Thanks for the tips.

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split(',')
        tags = l[1].split(';')
        for t in tags: 
            print(l[0],t.strip())
```

Comment: Please show the actual formatting of the CSV file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python import csv to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list) Please note that [asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Have you tried using the `str.split` method with `';'` as argument? Do you know already how to read a CSV file, or what exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, I've had part that opened file and read the context of it. I only could display the desired output. I've used the following and it worked: 
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split(',')
        tags = l[1].split(';')
        for t in tags: 
            print(l[0],t.strip())

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most straightforward approach would be (no libraries), to just do

```
new_data = []

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    # f.readline() if the csv has a header (skips first line)
    for line in f:
        split_kv = line.split(',')
        split_v = split_kv[1].split(';')
        for v in split_v:
            new_data.append((split_kv[0], v))
```