# Read IP address from text file to IPTABLES

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, iptables, ufw

Currently I am using ufw to manually add the ip rules by typing

```
sudo ufw allow from (my ip address)
```

I have retrieve the ip address of my client ip by doing some script calling from my database and save it to a .txt file.

this is the value i get

```
  ipaddress
 10.1.100.90
 10.1.100.91
```

Is it possible to read the ip address in the .txt file and save it to the rule instead of typing manually?

Comment: You are not supposed to edit question requirements after posting it once, and answers have been provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `bash` script like something below

```
#!/bin/bash

{ 
    # Skip the header line containing 'name  ipaddress'
    read skipLine;                     

    # Read the rest of the lines till end of the file
    while IFS= read -r name IP
    do
        # All the IP's are stored in the variable $IP. Use it
        # however you want
        printf  "%s %s\n" "$name" "$IP"

        # To print only the IPs, do
        # printf  "%s\n" "$IP"

    done
} <IPFile 

# IPFile - Input file name containing IP addresses. Replace it with your file
```

Comment: what is the `<IPFile` at the end?

Comment: @Fouzy: That is the file, you have the IP's stored in. Change that to actual file name you have

Comment: @Fouzy: Exactly. You need to use the `$IP` depending upon your need.

Comment: how do i ignore the "name" column?

Comment: @Fouzy: Why should you? Just access those contents inside the `$IP` variable

Comment: `printf  "%s %s\n" "$name" "$IP"` I try to remove the $NAME variable and nothing is show

Comment: @Fouzy: Refer my update in the answer containing only prinint IPs, just remove the `#` at beginning and remove other print statements

Comment: I have implement the code, still the value does not show.

Comment: @Fouzy: What do you expect to do when you don't show what you have attempted? Update your attempt in question.

Comment: Problem solved thanks. What I did was just removing the username.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple script in python that can read text file containing IP address list and then execute Linux command one by one on each IP address.A simple guide [Python Execute Unix / Linux Command Examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/)

Comment: I need some examples. I have never used python before and Iam new to linux  the command.

Comment: Please refer to the question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list-or-array-with-python


and then https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/