# Reading file's data in Python?

Tags: python

I have a file say `input.txt` which contains data in the following format ::

```
[8, 3, 4, 14, 19, 23, 10, 10, "Delhi"]
13
"Delhi"

8
10
19
```

How can i read the data in python or ruby. And I can see that my first row contains data which contains both integer and string.
And also how can I store it?

Comment: For first row, which data structure i should use to store both integer and string datatype?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list-or-array-with-python see this .it helps to u

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the source of your input text file, then I notice that each line is a valid Python expression so you could do something like:

```
with open(filename) as txt:
    evaluated_lines = [eval(line) for line in txt if line.strip()]
print(evaluated_lines)
```

The output is:

```
[[8, 3, 4, 14, 19, 23, 10, 10, 'Delhi'], 13, 'Delhi', 8, 10, 19]
```

Note that the Python list datatype can contain a mixture of sub-lists, integers, and strings