# Text to columns to array

Tags: python, list, file

I have been practising reading files in Python, as I am new to that particular area.

I have a text file like:

```
Hello,my,name,is,Jack
```

and I want to transfer that to a `list` like this:

```
["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "Jack"]
```

I tried doing this:

```
array = []
file = open("Names.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    array.append(line.split(","))
print(array)
```

but I got a really bizarre `error`:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 261, in choice
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is
empty
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to be where the error is. Do you call `random.choice` at any point in your code?

Comment: This error looks like it comes from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It may be with how you are declaring the random int. Do you declare seq yourself?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  no I didn't, the error is coming from the python library itslef it seem "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 261. Don't really know why, I haven't even touched it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list-or-array-with-python

Comment: @VasilisG.not a possible duplicate as my error is completely different

Comment: Is there any more to the stacktrace...like what `random` module function was called from where?

Answer (score -1):

You have not posted your full code (as in this code, you haven't used the `random` `module`), but it can be seen from the `error` that you are trying to do `random.choice` on an empty `list`.

You can reproduce the `error` like so:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So if you post the *whole* code, we can help you further, but otherwise you need to locate where you are calling `random.choice()` and debug what `list` you are calling it *on*.