# Python3 :how to import data from one text file into a few different arrays?

Tags: python-3.x

Python3 :how to import data from one text file into a few different arrays? The number of arrays needs to be given by another parameter n ,and the shape of arrays are diffrent.

Comment: Clarify what you are talking about with an example. Your language is unclear - it is impossible to import a name into a datastructure. You can import a name and then put the value it refers to inside a data structure. Is that what you want?

Comment: I mean i saved  a lot of point coordinates in a text file(one point's (x,y) in each line),and i wanna import these coordinates into a few different arrays. The number of arrays is given by an parameter n, and the shapes of these arrays are different.

Comment: Ok what's stopping you? Show us an example input file, your code, the output/result, and how the output/result differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can split line with , like

```
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
```

or with each line

```
f = open('file_name.ext', 'r')
x = f.readlines()
```

Check post for more 
[How to read text file into a list or array with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list-or-array-with-python)