# Loading text from file in python

Tags: python, file

im attempting to load single digit numbers line by line from file in python this code makes an error saying:

```
line 27, in <module>
environment.environment1.load_map(environmentVector)
TypeError: load_map() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

heres the source code: (main.py)

```
environmentVector = []
environment.environment1 = environment.environment(160, 100, 32, 32)
environment.environment1.load_map(environmentVector)
```

environment.py:

```
    def load_map(environmentVector):
        string = ''
        with open('map.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                string = f.readline()
                row = []
                for character in string:
                    if character == '0':
                        pass
                    elif character == '1':
                        environmentVector.append(environment)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this map.txt data?

Comment: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

Comment: zeroes and ones with 1 space between is whats in the map.txt theres about 10 lines of them

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: i want to store environment objects in a list (each environment having x,y coordinates) to make a map with boundaries where if the player runs into environment the collision will prevent them from walking through the rectangle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python   see here, looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, if `load_map` is a method of a class, the first argument it needs to take is `self`. Either add `self`, or mark `load_map` as a static method with `@staticmethod` See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944658/).

About your `load_map` function: Instead of iterating through the string, `split` it. It also makes sense to store a map like this to a 2D list. Try this:

```
def load_map(self, environmentVector):
    with open('map.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            nums = list(map(int, line.split()))
            environmentVector.append(nums)
```

Comment: it still throws the positional argument error even with your code

Comment: Did you read the linked SO question and make any modifications? If so, what modifications did you make?