# Select some words from an existing file in Python

Tags: python, list, file

I want to separate the exact words of a text file (*text.txt*) ending in a certain string by using 'endswith'. The fact is that my variable

```
h=[w for w in 'text.txt' if w.endswith('os')]
```

does not give what I want when I call it. On the other hand, if I try naming the open file

```
f=open('text.txt')
h=[w for w in f if w.endswith('os')]
```

does not work either. Should I convert the text into a list first?

Comment: I hope this is not duplicate. It is not the same as this [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python) although close to it.

Comment: just save the contents of one row first to a variable. You might be surprised by whats the at end of a line where you THINK it ends with 'os'.

Comment: Everyone of your answers work. Thank you. My question is why should I split the document before isolating the words ending in 'os'.

Comment: Paritosh Singh, do not understand your comment.

Comment: Each line `(w for w in f)` of the file will have a hidden newline character such as `'\n'`. So, none of the strings end with os. because they may end with `'os\n'` or something of that sort. While I've told you what's happened here, i highly recommend just looking at the variables, say with `h = [w for w in f]` and then just watch `h[0]` and see the actual line in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file first and then process it like this:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
h=[w for w in content.split() if w.endswith('os')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    words = [word for line in f for word in line.split() if word.endswith('os')]
```

Your first attempt does not read the file, or even open it. Instead, it loops over the characters of the string `'text.txt'` and checks each of them if it ends with `'os'`.

Your second attempt iterates over lines of the file, not words -- that's how a `for` loop works with a file handle.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the seperate words into a list (assuming they are seperated by spaces)

```
f = open('text.txt').read().split(' ')
```

Then to get a list of the words ending in "os", like you had:

```
h=[w for w in f if w.endswith('os')]
```

Comment: By splitting the words on spaces and nothing else, you fail to find words ending in `'os'` but followed by another whitespace character, such as line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('text.txt')
h=[w for w in f if w.endswith('os')]
```

This should work properly. Reasons it may be not working for you,

1. You should `strip` the line first. There may be hidden ascii chars, like "\n". You can use `rstrip()` method for that. Something like this.

`h=[w.rstrip() for w in f if w.rstrip().endswith('os')]`

2. After reading the file once, the `w` pointer reaches the End Of File (EOF), and hence any more read-operations will be in vain. To move the pointer back to the starting of the file, either use `seek` method, or re-open the file.