# Searching commands in Python from stored text files

Tags: python, file, search

Related to a [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503196/select-some-words-from-an-existing-file-in-python). I would like to know why the code:

```
import re
[w for w in g.split() if re.search('^..j..t..$', w)]
```

does not give an appropriate answer for a text g defined from a previous text file as:

```
f=open('text.txt')
g=f.read()
```

For example: take the text: "I would love to give my opinion about the White House, although nobody would listen." and write:

```
g='I would love t give my opinion about the White House, although nobody would listen.'
```

in this case when I type

```
[w for w in g.split() if re.search('^..t..g..$', w)]
```

the answer is a single '[ ]' and not '[although]' as expected.

Furthermore, can similar commands be executed for searching strings in that manner from a text file?

Comment: How is that not working?

Comment: It gives "[ ]" as output but it should return several words into the text.

Comment: I have included an example.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the thing. It is a matter of introducing as much dots as letters the wanted word contains. For example:

```
[w for w in h if re.search('^..t...g.$', w)]
```

returns

```
['although']
```

but

```
[w for w in h if re.search('^..t..g..$', w)]
```

gives nothing. 
I thought ^ and $ meant whatever before 't' and after 'g' respectively but they not. So, this command is not as useful as I thought.