# Substrings in every position for regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I know one can calculate the number of appearances of a certain pattern in a given text as explained in this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503196/select-some-words-from-an-existing-file-in-python).

Now, when defining terms for regular expressions, I am making use of commands such as

```
(r'.*ing$','VGER')
```

to define new patterns (in this case verbs in gerund time for words ending in 'ing').

My question is: how to define a similar pattern for word containing, say, the substring 'ng' **in every position** of the word?

Comment: Just use `ng`, `('ng','VGER')`. Are you sure you need a regex for this?

Comment: I want to classify the words, so a name such as VGER has to be given. Your ('ng',VGER') looks for every appearance of 'ng' in every word of the text?

Comment: `ng` regex pattern looks for `ng` anywhere in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, I found the code by myself:

```
(r'.*ng','VGER')
```

works.