# How can I import a .txt file to develop and algorithm to manipulate the data?

Tags: python, string, file, text, import

Lets say I have a .txt file that the first few lines of data looks like this:

v 0.188267 3.068606 0.003011
v -0.188267 3.068606 0.003011
v 0.168431 3.068606 0.013613
v -0.168431 3.068606 0.013613
v 0.146908 3.068606 0.020142
v -0.146908 3.068606 0.020142
v 0.124524 3.068606 0.022347

Ok, my goal is to be able to import the file into pycharm. And then I want to write an algorithm that turns the data into this format:

(0.188267, 3.068606, 0.003011),
(-0.188267, 3.068606, 0.003011),
(0.168431, 3.068606, 0.013613),
(-0.168431, 3.068606, 0.013613),
(0.146908, 3.068606, 0.020142),
(-0.146908, 3.068606, 0.020142),
(0.124524, 3.068606, 0.022347),

Then from there I want the data to be exported into another .txt file. In actuality the original .txt file is over 40,000 lines and doing this manually is tedious and time consuming.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you able to open the file? Once you have the data, have you tried using `.split()` on the imported lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python this is kind of the same, different format though

Comment: I'm new to python, like 2 days new to it. I don't even know how to include a text file in a directory so that pycharm can read the file. Like, instead of using the complete filepath, I just want to be able to use the text.txt without all the C:/users/... bit. And then from there, I don't know where to begin writing an algorithm that can traverse each line to change the data into the data I want.

Comment: You should learn to use python from the command line. It's much less of a headache.

Comment: I edited my answer and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    string = f.read()

formatted_string = string.replace("v ","")
formatted_string = formatted_string.replace("\n"," ")
str_numbers = formatted_string.split(" ")

with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for i,num in enumerate(str_numbers):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            f.write(f"({float(num)},")
        elif i % 3 == 1:
            f.write(f" {float(num)},")
        else:
            f.write(f" {float(num)}), ")
```

replace "filename.txt" with the name of your file. And make sure that you don't have spaces at the beginning and end of the file.

Edit: I've tested this on your example.

Comment: This almost works though. On the first line the output in the output text file is: (0.188267, 3.068606, but it stops there. There's no spaces after I Idk. I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: There's no blank spaces at the end of the file. I don't know why it stops on the first line, the error message reads:  f.write(f" {float(num)}), ")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.003011\n-0.188267'

Comment: The problem is probably that I need to replace enters with spaces. Try it now

Comment: Could you clarify? How It's on here the lines wrap and isn't side by side like it is on here. That's just how stackoverflow did it when I made the original post.

Comment: Yes, awesome. It worked but in the output text, how do I get it to stack on top of each other instead of placing them side by side?

Comment: Like this? : (0.188267, 3.068606, 0.003011),{enter} (-0.188267, 3.068606, 0.003011),

Comment: Awesomeness, I figured out the last bit. All I had to do is put \n in the:  f.write(f" {float(num)}), \n") Now I can move to the next bit. I appreciate you.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution. Great!