# Read file names from text file and print to list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a text file which contains list of file names and append that to a list.

I have written the code, but the output is repeated twice.

For example, there is text file named filelist.txt which contains the list of files (ex:- mango.txt).

When I run the code its printing mango.txt twice.

```
def im_ru(filelist1):
    with open(filelist1,"r") as fp:
        lines = fp.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            print(lines)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text file into a list or an array with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python)

Comment: "I have written the code, but the output is repeated twice." In your own words: where the code says `print(lines)`, what do you think this means to do? What is the content of `lines` at this point in the program? How many times will this code run? (Hint: is it inside a loop? What is the purpose of loops?) What do you want to happen each time through the loop? (Hint: did you want to print some *other* value?)

Answer (score 0):

You error is to print `lines` instead of `line` in your `for` loop

Use:

```
def im_ru(filelist1):
    with open(filelist1, 'r') as fp:
        # You have to remove manually the end line character
        lines = [line.strip() for line in fp]
    return lines
```

Usage:

```
>>> im_ru('data.txt')
['mango.txt', 'hello.csv']
```

Content of `data.txt`:

```
mango.txt
hello.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Print `line` instead

```
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-liner:

```py
from pathlib import Path
filenames = Path("filelist.txt").read_text().splitlines()
```