# Python: How to read each line from txt file instead of INPUT

Tags: python, input, python-requests

I was wondering If anyone can help me changing INPUT with a txt file which has more lines, and load each line, instead only one from the INPUT.
I want to change `x=input('Name:')` with opening a txt file and read each line at a time.

The code:

```py
x=input('Name:')
r=requests.get('http://mywebsite.com/a?=*.{}'.format(x))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a text file into a list or an array with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fhand = open("filename.txt, 'r')` to read in the file and loop over the lines of that file using a for loop. Like this:

```
for line in fhand:
    r=requests.get('http://mywebsite.com/a?=*.{}'.format(line))
```

Comment: Error: expected an idented block

Comment: That error is not related to my solution. Check in which line that error occurs.