# python file operations getting data

Tags: python

I tried to reach .txt file with path. Then I read every lines of files. And I imported that line to a empty array. But I can't see array's elements.

```
import random
from itertools import product
list=['']
sayac=0
with open('D:\wordlist\Yeni klasör\kelime.txt') as dosya:    
    for line in dosya.readline():
        list.insert(sayac,"")
        sayac+=1
for n in list:
    print(list)
```

Comment: Also do not use `list` as variable name. And you rather meant `print(n)`

Comment: Let's try not to shadow `built-in` `list` as your var. name.  Maybe `L.append(...)`?

Comment: Use a raw string if you use backslashes in the pathname.

Comment: You are not appending `line` to a list. You need something like `lst.append(line)`. (But actually `dosya.readline().splitlines()` already _is_ a list of lines, so the `for` loop is redundant.)

Comment: This helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676265/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-list-or-an-array-with-python

Comment: @j1-lee        Yes you are right. I noticed it. But I forgot to delete it.

Comment: @DanielHao - (Slightly pedantic) yet `L` is not a constant, therefore not a Pythonic name for a list.