# How to convert list lookalike into a list?

Tags: python, list, parsing, tuples

I'm reading in lines of data from a file in this format:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

...etc

However, when I do `type(dataInput[0])`, it tells me it's from type string. Although it looks like a list with the brackets and all. How can i make `dataInput[0]` directly into a list instead of string?

Here's some code:

```
fobj = open(selectedCase, 'r').read()
dataInput = re.split('\n', fobj)
```

I've seen threads such as:
[How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)
However that example doesn't have brackets in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn those strings into Python lists:

```
import ast

dataInput = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in fobj.splitlines()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> result = ast.literal_eval("['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']")
>>> type(result)
<class 'list'>
>>> result
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

You might want to use the file object as a context manager, to have Python close it again explicitly:

```
with open(selectedCase) as infh:
    dataInput = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in infh]
```

This uses the file object as an iterator as well, the loop will be given one line at a time from the file.

Comment: Taking the `.read()` off and just having `fobj` instead of `splitlines()` would be nicer... (assuming the original file data isn't needed again)

Comment: @JonClements: I was contemplating adding a `with` context manager and just looping over the file object, actually.

Comment: In for a penny, in for a pound and all that :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but if your data is clean can't you just do:

```
In [1]: x = "['a','b']"

In [2]: y = eval(x)

In [3]: y
Out[3]: ['a', 'b']

In [4]: type(y)
Out[4]: list
```

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything besides the caveat you already added -- the input might not be clean, and over time it can be tricky to keep track of the assumption that it must be. `eval` can easily be disastrous if the input is something like `os.system('rm -rf /blah')`. Since `ast.literal_eval` exists there's no good reason to make the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the files are really in the format you have specified, you could use [readlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) to have strings of the line.

If you don't want to `eval` the content in the file (because you don't trust the source, for example), you could then [split by the comma char](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) away the brackets and quotes. Additionally, if you want to check whether or not you have numbers or strings by using string's isxyz methods, like [isdigit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
    # The strip function gets rid of whitespace at the end of a line
    defaultInput = [eval(var.strip()) for var in f]  # A list comprehension

    print defaultInput[0]
    print type(defaultInput[0])
    print defaultInput[1]
    print type(defaultInput[1])
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
<type 'list'>
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
<type 'list'>
```

Where `f.txt` is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```