# How to count the number of times a word appears in each row of a csv file, in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv document in which each row contains a string of words. For each row, I want to know how many times each words appears in that row, how would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: can you give an overview of what the csv file looks like?
And what do you expect as the output?

Answer (score 0):

Move the row to a list, make it unique and count every object in list,

For converting to list [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

if result is more than one, print it.

Considered this as list `['a','b','a','c']`

```
z=['a','b','a','c']
u=set(z)
for i in u:
    if z.count(i)>1: print i,z.count(i)
```

Output:

```
`a 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
u = Counter(z)
print(u['a'])  # 2
print(u['b'])  # 1
```