# Convert items in a list element to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am forced to use comma separation in one of my input arguments to separate multiple values. So I end up with

```
my_string = ['a,b,c']
```

How can I convert this so that

```
my_new_string = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: `my_string` is a `list`, is there any scenario where it should hold more than one string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Why this `argparse` tag ? Can you explicit what's your use case ? It may helps people to provide better answer :)

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, since it's a string contained in a list... Anyway, apologies to all for calling it my_string - I should have called it my_list...!

Comment: @NiziL the use case is that the script is called from Jenkins, using Jenkins shell implemention. It's challenging to call the python script with a single space delimited argument without Jenkins injecting quotes, thus the second item in the space delimited argument is being interpreted as a new argument. Comma separating the input arg thus means Jenkins argument parsing does not interfere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way:

```
my_new_string = my_string[0].split(',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-liner:

```
my_new_string = [x for y in my_string for x in y.split(',')]
```

Comment: given that this question is tagged with `argparse` I don't think that this is the behavior OP is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-liner:

```
print(list(my_string[0].split(',')))
```

Comment: Try removing `list()`  and see.