# Python string to list in list

Tags: python, string, list

I just ran into an unsolved Solution ;)

I want to get a String into a list of lists.

```
string = r'ABC:=[[0,0,110],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09]];'
new_string = string.strip().split('=')
# now new_string[1][:-1] does look like a list of lists but everything i tried i just got a string.
```

Maybe someone here got an idea how I can get it like

```
data = [[0,0,110],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChrisMaes I don't think that duplicate directly answers OP's question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list) might be a better pick

Comment: @C.Nivs: I agree but cannot change my flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) library to transform the string into a data structure:

```py
import ast

# string is a module in python, to avoid aliasing, use
# variable names that ideally don't shadow builtins
mystring = r'ABC:=[[0,0,110],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09]];'

# get everything to the right of the = sign, and you don't need the semicolon
mystring = mystring.strip().split('=')[-1].rstrip(';')

# returns a list
mylist = ast.literal_eval(mystring)

[[0, 0, 110], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval` also works fine.

```
mystring = r'ABC:=[[0,0,110],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09,9e+09]];'

mystring = mystring.strip().split('=')[-1].rstrip(';')

data = eval(mystring)
print(data)
# output: [[0, 0, 110], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0, 9000000000.0]]
```