# converting a string to a list of words

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string to a list of words using python. I want to take something like the following:

```
string = '"This","is","a","string","with","words!"'
```

Then convert to something like this :

```
list = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'words']
```

Notice the omission of punctuation and spaces. What would be the fastest way of going about this?

Comment: [Use Split per This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Please always make sure that you post what you have tried along with your question.

Comment: string = '"This","is","a","string","with","words!"'       string.split(',')                                                                                                                                           
['"This"', '"is"', '"a"', '"string"', '"with"', '"words!"']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can quite literally be interpreted as python code using `ast.literal_eval`. It will produce a tuple but just turn it into a list.

```
>>> import ast
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(string.replace('!', ''))
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'words']
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [s.strip('"') for s in string.replace('!','').split(',')]
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'words']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is always in the format `"A","B",...`, this should work:

```
list = list(map(lambda x: x[1:-1], string.split(',')))
```

Comment: What about `!` ?

Comment: Seems like overkill when you could do it with one line using `my_string = '"This","is","a","string","with","words!"'.replace('"','').split(',')`

Comment: Using `map` and `lambda` here is less efficient than just a simple list comprehension just FYI. Either that or use `operator.itemgetter` when using `map` this way

Answer (score 0):

Here are some python in-built functions that can help you achieve your desired output:

```
stringO = '"This","is","a","string","with","words!"'
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
string = ""
for char in stringO:
   if char not in punctuations:
       string = string + char

string = string.split(',')
print(string)
```

Comment: What about `!` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'This is a string, with words!'
string_to_array = string.split()
print(string_to_array)
```