# Turning a List into an array of arrays in python

Tags: python

So I have an input text file that looks like this:

```
0,0,0,0  
0,0,1,0  
0,1,0,0  
0,1,1,1  
1,0,0,0  
1,0,1,0  
1,1,0,1  
1,1,1,1
```

I have successfully read all of these lines into a list which looks like this:

```
['0,0,0,0' , '0,0,1,0' , '0,1,0,0' , '0,1,1,1' , '1,0,0,0' , '1,0,1,0' , '1,1,0,1', '1,1,1,1']
```

My code for creating this list is

```
fileName = input("Filename:")
    file = open(fileName,'r')
    training = np.array(file.read().splitlines())
    for i in range(len(training)):
        a.append(training[i])
```

However I was wondering how I can turn the list into something that looks like this:

```
[ [0,0,0,0] , [0,0,1,0] , [0,1,0,0] , [0,1,1,1] , [1,0,0,0] , [1,0,1,0] , [1,1,0,1] , [1,1,1,1] ]
```

If it is not clear, my list has value of type string but I want the type to be in int as well as in the format above.

Please let me know if there is a way I can get this end result through changing my code or somehow doing some sort of conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    l = [[int(x) for x in x.split(",")] for x in f]
```

---

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8d5ebaab51)

Comment: Isn't having two variables named `x` like this potentially problematic?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the strings on `,` and then convert to `int`:

```
a = [[int(n) for n in x.split(',')] for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
fileName = input("Filename:")
with open(fileName) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
arr=list()
for line in lines:
    arr.append(list(map(int, line.rstrip().split(","))))
```

Here `arr` is your desired `list of lists`. What I am doing is reading the file lines and storing it in `lines` then, iterating through `lines` and spiting each line by `,` and then mapping them as `int`. If you do not perform the map function, then it will be `str`.

Note I am using `rstrip()` to remove the trailing new line character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

```
training_arr = []
fileName = input("Filename:")
with open(fileName,'r') as fileName:
    training_arr = [[int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in line.split(',')] for line in fileName.readlines()]

print(training_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is grab each element of the array and then each element of the string.

Eg. You can first grab `'0,0,0,0'` split by `','` and **add each 0 to an array**.. **after getting n arrays, you can add them all to a single array**.

P.S. you may want to confer the strings to int before you add them to an array, and should consider doing that once you've grabbed each 0 separately!