# How to add single quote to values in list?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my list

```
x = ['India,America,Australia,Japan']
```

How to convert above list into

```
x = ['India','America','Australia','Japan']
```

I tried it using strip and split method but it doesn't work.

Comment: `x = x[0].split(",")`

Comment: Its working fine thank you @L3viathan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: There is difference between what you suggest and my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn that list into the string and split in commas:

```
test = ['India,America,Australia,Japan']

result = "".join(test).split(",")

print(result)
```

Output is this:

```
['India', 'America', 'Australia', 'Japan']
```

or you can use regex library.

```
import re

x = "".join(['India,America,Australia,Japan'])

xText = re.compile(r"\w+")
mo = xText.findall(x)
print(mo)
```

The findall method looks for all the word characters and does not include comma. Finally it returns a list.

Output is this:

```
['India', 'America', 'Australia', 'Japan']
```