# Converting a Comma Separated String to a List of Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a long string to a list of strings for each item separated with comma.

```
list = ['05-19.scl, 05-22.scl, 05-24.scl, 06-41.scl']
```

to :

```
desired_list= ['05-19.scl', '05-22.scl', '05-24.scl', '06-41.scl']
```

Comment: This is very basic if you don't mind me saying. But `desired_list = list[0].split(", ")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Thanks you all. yes after another 5 min of searching I found the answer on google. Sorry - Will look a little deeper next time

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> listObj = ['05-19.scl, 05-22.scl, 05-24.scl, 06-41.scl']
>>> a = [x.split(',') for  x in listObj][0]
>>> a
['05-19.scl', ' 05-22.scl', ' 05-24.scl', ' 06-41.scl']
```