# Every item in string to item in list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

```
names = "john, maria, william, jenny"
```

Given the variable `names`, how to output `['john', 'maria', william', 'jenny']`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `str.split()` with the argument `", "`

```
>>> names.split(", ")
['john', 'maria', 'william', 'jenny']
```