# Python Conversion string into int array

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert in Python 3.x string like this: `{str} '[21,2,14]'` into int array like this: `{list: 3} [21,2,14]` ?

Comment: you can use ``json``, you can use ``ast``, or you can write your own parser

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Did you remember to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) before posting? This is a pretty standard task, with many examples online already.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), a [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/967621) alternative to `eval`:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval('[21,2,14]'))
# [21, 2, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `ast` for tasks like this - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

```
import ast 
input_values = '[21,2,14]'
eval_input = ast.literal_eval(input_values)
```

outputs `[21, 2, 14]`