# In Python how to convert a string into list

Tags: python

What command in python can be used to make the string ST = “WORK,IS,DONE” a list [“WORK”,”IS”,”DONE”]?

I am trying this but its not working

```py
ST = txt.split(",")

print(ST)
```

Comment: That's the correct function, what do you mean by "it isn't working?"

Comment: I don't know what is `txt` but if your variable `ST` holds these words then you should `ST.split(',')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the string defined under ST and not txt, which appears to be the issue.

```
st = "WORK,IS,DONE"
st = st.split(sep=",")
print(st)
```