# Python make list from string

Tags: python

I have column with this kind of data:

[image]

I want to count how many times valu occur in a row. It is a string, so I want to convert this '63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63' to this ['63','63','63'...].

I there any way to do this quickly?
Thanks

Comment: `row.split(',')`

Comment: What is the source / type of your `row`s, do you use a framework like _pandas_? Some context and a [example] is required to complete and clarify your question. Otherwise I would suggest to research first: e.g.  search for [`[python] string to list`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+string+to+list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if given string is s

```
l=s.split(',')
```

l is the required list

Comment: The return value from split is a list so you convert a list to a list. Why?

Comment: haha yea did it by mistake thankyou for identifying