# How to convert String to list in Python 3

Tags: python, string, list

After user input, variable colors = "58, 234, 209", it is string. I need to convert it to list - colors = [58, 234, 209]. Which way I can do it. Thank you.

```
color = ("Enter color you like, something like that 58, 234, 209. ")
colors = input(color)
```

Comment: Use the `split` function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python

Comment: A string is already a list (sequence) of characters

Comment: Remove whitespaces, then split based on comma, then convert each item to int:
color = ("Enter color you like, something like that 58, 234, 209. ")
colors = input(color)
listOfColors = colors.replace(" ", "").split(',')
listOfColors = [int(x) for x in listOfColors]
print(listOfColors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have some non-space characters in there like `,`, you'll want to use a flexible splitter, like `re.split`:

```py
import re
colors = input('Enter color you like, something like that 58, 234, 209. ')
colors = list(map(int, re.split(r'[^\d]+', colors)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = colors.split()
```

This will split on each of the spaces in the string

Comment: But list's components still strings, it must be integers like [58, 234, 209]

Comment: @marzymster you didn't specify you needed to convert the contents to integers, just that you needed to know how to split. use `int(colors[index])` whenever you use them to convert to an integer