# Converting a string to list through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, pycharm

The string value

```
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"
```

I need the output to be as a list

```
list = [ "new=user","pass=h[]@","repalce=que" ]

  

I am new to python just want to know how to deal with these type convertions
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844118/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-string-to-list-in-python)

Comment: Don't use `list` as name, it will overwrite the built-in `list()`.

Comment: how come `pass=h[]@` became `test=h[]@`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split method as follows:

```
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"

splitList = value.split(",")

print(splitList)
```

The split method takes the character that you want to split the sentence on as a parameter.

Comment: You get extra quotes `['[new=user', 'pass=h[]@', 'repalce=que]']` You have to strip that quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in this particular case by the following command

```
value_list = value[1:-1].split(',')
```

This way you will first get rid of the brackets (first and last character) and then split by the comma. I do not think there is a more elegant way since this is a rather rare case. I would recommend loading lists as lists or other variables in their correct format and avoid changing the type.

Comment: Thankyou! it worked, but what if value has an extra ',' ? like value = "[new=user,pass=h[],@,repalce=que]"

Comment: Then there is nothing you can really do but manually make sure you avoid these cases or when saving the file using a different way to separate the items, like with a semi-colon: "[new=user;pass=h[],@;repalce=que]"

Answer (score 0):

you can use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```py
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"
result = value.split(',')
```

please note that `list` is a type. I recommend not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: Thankyou! it worked, but what if value has an extra ',' ? like value = "[new=user,pass=h[],@,repalce=que]"

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a list comprehension like this:

```
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"

new_value = [t.replace('pass', 'test') for t in value[1:-1].split(',')]

print(new_value)
```

**Output:**

```
['new=user', 'test=h[]@', 'repalce=que']
```

**Note:**

This **only** works for this particular case.

Also, there's no "type conversion" here

Answer (score 0):

Clean the string thyen convert string to list by string.split()

```
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"
value = value [1:-1].split(",")
print(value)
```

output #

```
['new=user', 'pass=h[]@', 'repalce=que']
```

Comment: Thankyou! it worked, but what if value has an extra ',' ? like value = "[new=user,pass=h[],@,repalce=que]"

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `[]@` is not supposed to be taken as list. So this is my solution, maybe it would be better to use regex but whatever.

```
value = "[new=user,pass=h[]@,repalce=que]"
def func(x):
    n=len(x)
    x=list(x)
    s=e=-1
    for i in range(0,n-2,1):
        if x[i]=='[' and x[i+1]!=']' and x[i+2]!='@':s=i
        if x[i]==']' and x[i-1]!='[' and x[i+1]!='@':e=i
    x[s]=x[e]=''
    x=''.join(x)
    x=x.split(',')
    return x
print(func(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string

```
# Python code to convert string to list
  
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li
 
str1 = "Item1 Item2 Item3"
print(Convert(str1))
```

**Output:**

```
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
```